# Programmatically Controlling an iOS data connection

Tags: ios, iphone, cellular-network

I was recently asked to create an iOS app for a client which controls all other installed apps' access to cellular data. For instance, the user would be able to turn off cellular data access to all apps but Safari.

I assumed that this wouldn't be possible because of sand-boxing but couldn't find any relevant info via Google or the developer's docs, so thought I'd ask the question here - is there a specific class or framework I should investigate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't , Apple does not allow such approaches . So there is no helping class or framework at all.

Comment: I thought this may be the case. Thank you